# Tomcat - how to create multiple servers with separate configuration

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I'd like to run a separate Tomcat Server in my Eclipse/STS environment to mirror the production environment. I managed to create a new Tomcat server with copy/paste, but the "Server" section under navigator still shows only a single Tomcat server. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Did you change the port numbers in server.xml file for the second instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st. Copy-paste the configuration located in Servers project, and rename it to the_new_server

[image]

2nd. Copy-paste the server in "Servers" view

[image]

3rd. Double click the newly created server, fill the fields as shown, use the Browse button for choosing the configuration path, otherwise won't work, and save

[image]

4th. Right click the new server and select Properties. Click "Switch location".
A dialog will appear asking you "Do you want to rename...", but this is not important, if you click "yes", the config folder will be automatically renamed to the_new_server-config.

[image]

5th. That's it.